# R newbie: how to create an array from a set of coordinate vectors?

Tags: r, vector, multidimensional-array, coordinates

Suppose I have a set of measurements taken at various locations in a 3D space. The locations of the measurements have the coordinate vectors

```
x <- c(0,1,2,3)
y <- c(4,5,6)
z <- c(7,8)
```

Thus, e.g., the measurement nearest the origin was done at location=`(0,4,7)`. From the above coordinate vectors, I want to create a 3D array--and only an array. @bnaul: These are coordinates for the centers of voxels, to which I want to assign values. My intention is, in pcode,

```
arr <- magic( c(0,1,2,3) , c(4,5,6) , c(7,8) )
# arr is now a 3D array filled with NAs
value1 -> arr[0, 4, 7]
value2 -> arr[3, 5, 7]
# and so on, but if one does
valueBad -> arr[4,3,2] # one should get an error, as should, e.g.,
valueBad2 -> arr[3,4,5]
```

But I suspect I've been "thinking in NetCDF" for too long: basically what I want to do above is assign [coordinates](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/BestPractices.html#Coordinate%20Systems) to an array, which I don't believe one can do in R.

Comment: Can you describe how you intend to use this array? If you're storing the measurements, then a 3D array is appropriate; if you're just trying to get a list of coordinates, then as @Arun and Anthony suggest you could just use a 2D matrix, where each row contains one (x,y,z)-tuple.

Answer (score 1):

```
# starting data
x <- c(0,1,2,3)
y <- c(4,5,6)
z <- c(7,8)

# find every combo
w <- expand.grid( x , y , z )

# convert to a matrix
v <- as.matrix( w )

# view your result
v
```

Comment: He's trying to make a 3D array, not a 2D matrix. This answer and the above comment both miss the point.

Comment: @bnaul I too am puzzled about what sort of 3D array could be constructed from 9 values...

Comment: @bnaul, the OP says: `the above looks right. I can not cast it from data.frame to array with...` and his question at the end doesn't talk about it as well.

Comment: @Arun Yeah, I'm just trying to decide which statement to believe: that they want a 3D array, or that the output from expand.grid looks right. Those two are seemingly contradictory...

Comment: @joran, I kind of make sense that he wants the points (which are in 3D space) in an array. I can't make sense of the other case other than may be `array(0, dim=c(4,3,2))` and then start filling values..?

Comment: I guessed the second one, but you guys are probably right about what he actually meant. Maybe someday we'll find out for sure!

Answer (score 1):

alternatively, this also might help.  please clarify your desired result :)

```
# starting data
x <- c(0,1,2,3)
y <- c(4,5,6)
z <- c(7,8)

# create a 4 x 3 x 2 array
v <- 
    array( 
        # start out everything as missing..
        NA , 
        # ..and make the lengths of the dimensions the three lengths.
        dim = 
            c( length( x ) , length( y ) , length( z ) ) 
    )

# view your result
v

# now populate it with something..
# for now, just populate it with 1:24
v[ , , ] <- 1:length(v)

# view your result again
v
```

Comment: Instead of first making an array full of `NA`s, put there the vector with your values, x changing fastest, then y, then z.

Comment: @cbeleites i'm not doing anything else till we get a revised question ;)

Comment: I meant that for TomRoche, not for you. I was writing basicahlly the same answer you wrote, but with the question what he wants to fill in as the first line...

Comment: @cbeleites ahh gotcha sorry :)

Comment: No problem, I should have addressed the comment to TomRoche.

Answer (score 0):

```
 array(NA, dim=c(4,3,2), 
   dimnames=list( x = c(0,1,2,3),
     y = c(4,5,6),
     z = c(7,8) ) )
, , z = 7

   y
x    4  5  6
  0 NA NA NA
  1 NA NA NA
  2 NA NA NA
  3 NA NA NA

, , z = 8

   y
x    4  5  6
  0 NA NA NA
  1 NA NA NA
  2 NA NA NA
  3 NA NA NA
```